# linear algebra - equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine real number(s)for  $a,b$ such that the system has no solution, has a unique solution, and has more than one solution: 
>   $$\begin{align*}
> x-2y+az-t&=1\\
> -x+y-z+t&=-1\\
> (a+1)y-a^2z+at&=0\\
> (b+1)y-abz-a^2t&=b
> \end{align*}$$

I could not transform the matrix into row reduced form.So that I could not find $a$ and $b$. I will be glad if someone could solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Your matrix will have $a$ and $b$ indicated. You then have to be careful with them.

(I hope I didn't make any silly arithmetic or algebra mistakes; but even if I did, you should be able to see how one proceeds: doesn't matter what $a$ and $b$ are, so long as you are careful not to *divide* by an expression containing them, since you won't know ahead of time that what you are dividing by is not zero).

The augmented matrix for the system is:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & a+1 & -a^2 & a & 0\\
0 & b+1 & -ab & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Proceed as usual. First, we add the first row to the second row:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & -1 & a-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a+1 & -a^2 & a & 0\\
0 & b+1 & -ab & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Then, multiply the second row by $-1$:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1-a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a+1 & -a^2 & a & 0\\
0 & b+1 & -ab & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Now, subtract $(a+1)$-times the second row from the third row; multiplying the second row by $-(a+1)$ gives $(0\quad -(a+1)\quad (a^2-1)\quad 0\>|\>0)$, so we have:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1-a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & a & 0\\
0 & b+1 & -ab & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Multiply the third row by $-1$:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1-a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a & 0\\
0 & b+1 & -ab & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Now subtract $(b+1)$-times the second row from the fourth row. Multiplying the second row by $-(b+1)$ gives $(0\quad (b+1)\quad (ab+a-b-1)\quad 0\>|\>0)$, so we get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1-a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a & 0\\
0 & 0 & a-b-1 & -a^2 & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Now, subtract $(a-b-1)$-times the third row from the fourth row. Multiplying the third row by $-(a-b-1)$ gives $(0\quad 0\quad (1+b-a)\quad (a^2-ab-a)\>|\>0)$, so we get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -2 & a & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1-a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -(ab+a) & b
\end{array}\right).$$
Now we can figure out the rank easily enough.

If $-(ab+a) = -a(b+1)\neq 0$, then the coefficient matrix has rank $4$ and the augmented matrix has rank $4$, so the system has exactly one solution.

If, however, $-a(b+1)=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then the coefficient matrix would have rank $3$ and the augmented matrix would have rank $4$, so that would be no solutions.

And, finally, if $-a(b+1)=0$ and $b=0$, then both the coefficient and augmented matrices have rank $3$, so the system would have an infinite number of solutions.

So now, it's just a matter of determining what are the conditions on $a$ and $b$ that give you those three possibilities. **Suggestion:** Deal with them in the inverse order I listed them: first the case where $-a(b+1)=0$ and $b=0$, because you'll be able to say exactly what $a$ and $b$ are; then consider the middle case; and finally the first mentioned case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.I was confused with a and b's when I was doing row reductions.Thank you again for the each steps that you have done and for your clear explanations.

Comment: @Piril: Arturo's answer is compeletly right. :)